# Creation of temporary tables and joining them

Tags: sql

I am trying to learn how to connect 2 temporary tables. Can someone correct the code or give a suggestion? Thank you for your time.

```
     SELECT l.CMAGY AS 'AGENCY', l.cmschn AS 'MASTER_CHAIN', l.CMCHN AS 'CHAIN', p.PDSTR AS 'STORE NUMBER', p.PDWEDT AS 'WK_ENDING',
p.PDQSLD AS 'POS_UNITS',
p.PDQSLD * p.PDRSP AS 'POS_BILLING',
p.PDQSLD * p.PDRPRC AS 'POS_MSRP',
p.PDQOH AS 'Retailer_on_hand_units'


INTO #temp2
FROM REPIT.LEVYDTA.POSDTLM p
JOIN REPIT.LEVYDTA.LDSCHNM l
ON p.PDAGY= l.CMAGY AND p.PDCHN = l.CMCHN
Where p.pdwedt = 20210731;
```

And the first table

```
SELECT s.DEAGY AS 'AGENCY', l.cmschn AS 'MASTER_CHAIN', s.DECHN AS 'CHAIN', s.DESTR AS 'STORE NUMBER', s.DEWEDT AS 'WK_ENDING',  
CASE 
WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND s.DEAGY = 10 AND s.DECHN = 'WM' THEN s.DEQTY ELSE 0
END AS  'OUTBOUND_UNITS',
CASE
WHEN sm.DEIO='I' AND sm.DEAGY = 10 AND sm.DECHN = 'WM' THEN -1 * sm.DEQTY ELSE 0
END AS 'RET_UNITS',
CAST (( CASE WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND s.DEAGY = 10 AND s.DECHN = 'WM' THEN s.DEQTY ELSE '0' END) AS int) 
- 
CAST ( ( CASE WHEN sm.DEIO='I' AND sm.DEAGY = 10 AND sm.DECHN = 'WM' THEN -1 * sm.DEQTY ELSE '0' END )   AS int) AS 'NET_UNITS',
CASE
WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND s.DEAGY = 10 AND s.DECHN = 'WM' THEN s.DEQTY * s.DERSP ELSE '0'
END AS OB_BILLING,
CASE
WHEN sm.DEIO='I' AND sm.DEAGY = 10 AND sm.DECHN = 'WM'  THEN (-1 * SM.DEQTY) * sm.DERSP ELSE 0
END AS RET_BILLING,
CAST ( ( CASE WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND s.DEAGY = 10 AND s.DECHN = 'WM' THEN s.DEQTY * s.DERSP ELSE '0' END) 
     AS MONEY) 
- 
CAST ( ( CASE WHEN sm.DEIO='I' AND sm.DEAGY = 10 AND sm.DECHN = 'WM' THEN (-1 * sm.DEQTY) * sm.DERSP ELSE '0' END )   AS MONEY) AS 'NET_BILLING',


CASE 
WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND s.DEAGY = 10 AND s.DECHN = 'WM' THEN s.DEQTY * s.DERPRC ELSE 0
END AS OB_MSRP, 
CASE
WHEN sm.DEIO='I' AND sm.DEAGY = 10 AND sm.DECHN = 'WM' THEN ( -1 * sm.DEQTY) * sm.DERPRC ELSE 0
END AS RET_MSRP,
CAST ( ( CASE WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND s.DEAGY = 10 AND s.DECHN = 'WM' THEN s.DEQTY * s.DERPRC ELSE '0' END) AS MONEY) 
- 
CAST ( ( CASE WHEN sm.DEIO='I' AND sm.DEAGY = 10 AND sm.DECHN = 'WM' THEN (-1 * sm.DEQTY) * sm.DERPRC ELSE '0' END )   AS MONEY) AS 'NET_MSRP'


INTO #temp1
FROM REPIT.SMPDTA.SMPDTLM s
JOIN REPIT.LEVYDTA.LDSCHNM l
ON s.DEAGY=l.CMAGY AND s.DECHN=l.CMCHN
JOIN LEVYDTA.SMPRTNM sm
ON s.DEAGY=sm.DEAGY AND s.DECHN=sm.DECHN AND s.DESTR=sm.DESTR
where s.DEWEDT = 20210731 AND s.DECHN='WM';
```

After that I need to connect them on such columns
ON s.DEAGY=p.pdagey AND s.DECHN=p.pdchn AND s.DESTR=p.pdstr AND s.DEWEDT=p.pdWEDT;

That's what I have for right now (which doesn't work).

```
SELECT t1.DEAGY, t1.DECHN, t1.DESTR, t1.DEWEDT,
t2.PDAGY, t2.PDCHN, t2.PDSTR, t2.PDWEDT
FROM #temp1
INNER JOIN #temp2
ON t1.DEAGY=t2.pdagy
AND t1.DECHN=t2.pdchn
AND t1.DESTR=t2.pdstr
AND t1.DEWEDT=t2.pdWEDT;
```

Comment: I need a temp table. However, if you know how to do it with CTE, could you please help with the code with CTE? Though I probably will need a temp table eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you want, but you can write your query as follows

```
SELECT s.*,p.*
FROM
  (SELECT s.DEAGY,s.DECHN,s.DESTR,s.DEWEDT
  FROM REPIT.SMPDTA.SMPDTLM s
  JOIN REPIT.LEVYDTA.LDSCHNM l
  ON s.DEAGY=l.CMAGY AND s.DECHN=l.CMCHN
  JOIN LEVYDTA.SMPRTNM sm
  ON s.DEAGY=sm.DEAGY AND s.DECHN=sm.DECHN
  WHERE (s.DEWEDT between @LastYearLWDATE and @LastWeekDATE)) s

JOIN

  (SELECT p.pdagey,p.pdchn,p.pdstr,p.pdWEDT
  FROM REPIT.LEVYDTA.POSDTLM p
  JOIN REPIT.LEVYDTA.LDSCHNM l
  ON p.PDAGY= l.CMAGY AND p.PDCHN = l.CMCHN
  WHERE p.pdwedt = ‘20210731’) p

ON s.DEAGY=p.pdagey AND s.DECHN=p.pdchn AND s.DESTR=p.pdstr AND s.DEWEDT=p.pdWEDT
```

Comment: for some reason this code didn't work. I shared the whole code that I use for SQL, if you may look at see what needs to be adjusted, I will greatly appreciate.

Comment: I have updated my instructions. If you know, I will greatly appreciate.

Comment: Your code is not clear. Where do you have a problem with the code now? Did you make the wrong joins?

Comment: it is my bad, there was an issue with the code and i needed to revise quite a few things. I have provided an updated version, let me know if you know what is wrong with this join of temporary tables. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Tables # temp1 and #temp2 are created correctly and have information?

Comment: Try to solve the problem step by step. See temp1 has data, then go to # temp2 and then check the connection between the two